# VB.Net Reading Resource Binary File

Tags: vb.net

I have a resource in named `StoreCode`, I can't seem to read the file using:

```
Dim readBinaryFile As BinaryReader
readBinaryFile = New BinaryReader(My.Resources.StoreCode)
```

There is an error:

`Value of type:'1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'`

How do I correctly `read` the Binary File?

Comment: HINT: Seems `My.Resources.StoreCode` is a `byte[]` for that reason you need to copy it to a `MemoryStream` object and then use a `BinaryReader` to read the stream's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems `My.Resources.StoreCode` is a `byte[]` for that reason you need to copy it to a `MemoryStream` object and then use a `BinaryReader` to read the stream's content.

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream(My.Resources.StoreCode)
    Using readBinaryFile As New BinaryReader(ms)
        'read operations
    End Using
End Using
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`My.Resources.StoreCode` is probably a an array of bytes. Instead, it needs to be a file stream, similar to this:

```
Dim readBinaryFile As BinaryReader
Dim fs As System.IO.Stream = File.Open(pathstring, FileMode.Open)
readBinaryFile = New BinaryReader(fs)
```